# iOS Simulator Always resets Location to "None"

Tags: ios, location, ios-simulator

I'm debugging a location-aware app, and getting frustrated with the iOS simulator. For some reason every time I run my app from Xcode the Location setting (under the Debug menu) resets to "None" (from "Custom Location…").

Anyone know how to prevent this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In your project select edit scheme and go to the option tab. Edit default location to your liken.

[image]

Check [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/CustomizingYourExperienceThroughXcodeSchemes/CustomizingYourExperienceThroughXcodeSchemes.html) for other customizable option. If you want to create a permanent location create a GPX file with editor or [online generator](http://gpx-poi.com/)

Comment: For another advanced GPX creator, this works quite well for route creations.  http://www.gpxcreator.com/

Comment: problem with this is that there is no option for custom location.

Answer (score 20):

You can set it in *Default location* option as Shams Ahmed mentioned, but there is one more option.

If you want XCode to keep your preference you made in *Debug – Location* menu in iOS Simulator, simply deselect the *Allow Location Simulation* checkbox in the *Edit scheme* menu. Now the location will not be reset to "None" and iOS Simulator will respect your location setting.

Comment: That is actually the solution I have been looking for!

Comment: This should be the selected answer!

Comment: This does keep the simulator's custom setting. But then the app is unable to find it's location when launched directly on a device.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a .gpx file but still not working. Then I created a new one using the [online generator](http://gpx-poi.com/) described above by Shams Ahmed and this one is working fine now. The difference between the old and the new .gpx file was, that I was using a comma in my coordinates (14,99889), not a dot (14.99889)!