# CLLocationManager doesn't work on iOS 8 Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I've a very strange problem.
In my app I read the actual coordinates with `CLLocationManager`, but on iOS 8 simulator doesn't work. On iOS Physical Device all works fine and even on iOS 7 simulator.

```
    self.manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.manager.delegate = self;
    self.manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0"))
    {
        NSUInteger code = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];
        if (code == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined &&
            ([self.manager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)] ||

             [self.manager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]))
        {
            if(Get_Plist_Object(@"NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription"))
            {
                [self.manager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
            }
            else if(Get_Plist_Object(@"NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription"))
            {
                [self.manager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Info.plist does not contain NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription or NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription");
            }
        }
    }

    [self.manager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Comment: Try to set custom location for the simulator Debug > Location > Custom, or even first try to set it to one of the default values, like Apple.

Comment: I've a custom location set on my current position. After change it and set Apple it works. Very strange.... it's a bug ?

Comment: I think it has something to do with simulator always reseting custom locations to none(0,0) heres a topic about it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643779/ios-simulator-always-resets-location-to-none I can't tell you exact reason, I don't know it.

Comment: The iOS 8 simulator seems to clear the location every time it launches, or something more random. I think it's terribly buggy. The Xcode 5.X simulator didn't have this issue. I have to manually re-pick the location every time I run where I need it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set a custom location.

Go into the top bar menus, hit `Debug`, then `Location`, and select your choice :)

Comment: I've a custom location set on my current position

Comment: Did you added the "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" in the Info.plist?

Comment: Yes. The problem was the Custom Location. With a default one works